# how to do this in a for loop in Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, matrix

I have a 3-dimensial matrix `W` of size `160x170x18` and I want to compute the difference 
between each sucessive matrices inside W.

For example `diff1 = W(:,:,1) - W(:,:,2)` and `diff2 = W(:,:,2) - W(:,:,3)`, etc ...

Next I want to select some special parts of the resulting matrices, For example:

```
NewDiff1 = [diff1(20:50,110:140); diff1(60:90,110:140)];
```

and the same thing for the other matrices.
finally I want to compute the mean of each matrix and the error as follow:

```
mean1 = mean(mean(NewDiff1));
er1 = 0.1-abs(mean1);
```

I succeeded to do this for each matrix alone, but prefer to do all at once in a for loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression

```
diff1 = diff(W,1,3)
```

will return, in your example, a `160*170*17` matrix where `diffW(:,:,1) = W(:,:,2) - W(:,:,1)`, which isn't quite what you want.  But

```
diff1 = (-1)*diff(W,1,3)
```

does, if my arithmetic is good, give you the differences you want.  From there on you need something like:

```
newdiff1 = [diff1(20:50,110:140,:);diff1(60:90,110:140,:)];
```

and

```
means = mean(mean(newdiff1));
er1 = 0.1 - abs(mean1);
```

I haven't tested this thoroughly on matrices of the size you are working with, but it seems to work OK on smaller tests.

Comment: I don't think this is what the question is asking. The post shows that they clearly know how to do the diff along the correct axis, it seems like they are saying that in addition to the tensor `W` they might also have tensors called `Y`, `Z`, etc., all needing the same weird diff treatment; and for the `diff1`, `diff2`, etc., it looks like they *don't* want the result plugged into one big matrix at the end. That's why just pushing them into a cell array is probably better.

Comment: I found another solution:

dff = diff(W,1,3);
a = dff([20:50,60:90],110:140,:);
meanN = mean(reshape(a,[],size(a,3)));
erN = .1 - abs(meanN);

Answer (score 1):

Store your matrices into a [cell array](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/06/21/cell-arrays-and-their-contents/) and then just loop through the contents of the cell array and apply the same differencing logic to each thing. Be careful to use the `{}` syntax with a cell array to get its contents, rather than `()` which gives you the cell at a particular location.